# Android, Async/Await throwing exception after activity navigation

Tags: android, xamarin, async-await

I'm writing an Android app in Xamarin that populates a list with data from a HttpClient. There are multiple screens.

Here's the issue:

I make an asynchronous call to go get some Json data for a list. I fire this right when the user navigates to the Activity that shows the list. This works fine if the user doesn't navigate away. The UI is responsive while the network call is firing. Great.

But if the user quickly navigates away to a different screen, then navigates back before the async calls complete, an unhandled exception is thrown with no details. I assume what is happening is the httpClient is returning data, but it is returning it to the disposed activity.

I've tried using cancellation tokens, so when they navigate away, I call Cancel on the cancellationTokenSource. I may be doing it wrong though, are you supposed to wait until you get confirmation that the async call has cancelled before continuing somehow?

What is the proper way to prevent this problem?

CODE:

in the fragment:

```
private async void SwipeRefreshLayout_Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cancelRefreshCall = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var swipeRefreshLayout = View.FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swipeRefreshLayout1);
    swipeRefreshLayout.Refreshing = true;
    _items.Clear();
    List<item> items = new List<item>();

    try
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await _itemService.RefreshItems(_cancelRefreshCall.Token);
                restaurants = await _itemService.GetLatestItems(_cancelRefreshCall.Token);
            }
            catch (System.OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }, _cancelRefreshCall.Token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    swipeRefreshLayout.Refreshing = false;
}
```

Here's the button to navigate away:

```
    private void SubmitItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_cancelRefreshCall != null)
        {
            _cancelRefreshCall.Cancel();
        }

        // redirect to preference page once done
        var fgManager = this.Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        var fragment = this.Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(Constants.LeahNutrinoPrefTag);

        if (fragment== null)
        {
            fgManager.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, new ProfileFragment(), Constants.ProfileTag);
        }
        else
        {
            fgManager.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, fragment, Constants.ProfileTag);
        }

        fgManager.Commit();
    }
```

Comment: Can you supply some code samples in the question of what you have tried?

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the fact that you're closing over the _`cancelRefreshCall` field? Whenever you assign a new value to it, the closure in the running task will point to the new, non-canceled `CancellationTokenSource`.

You can try the following code instead:

```
private async void SwipeRefreshLayout_Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cancelRefreshCall?.Cancel();
    _cancelRefreshCall = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _cancelRefreshCall.Token;
    var swipeRefreshLayout = View.FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swipeRefreshLayout1);
    swipeRefreshLayout.Refreshing = true;
    _items.Clear();
    List<item> items = new List<item>();

    try
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await _itemService.RefreshItems(token);
                restaurants = await _itemService.GetLatestItems(token);
            }
            catch (System.OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }, token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    swipeRefreshLayout.Refreshing = false;
```

Comment: I will try this. I have implemented a temporary solution. The button that navigates, when its clicked, all it does it cancel the token source. I know that will throw a OperationCanceledException, so I catch it, and in the catch block I navigate away. It takes a long time for the exception to be caught. What this means is the user will not be navigated to the other screen until we have confirmation that the task was canceled. So it looks like its taking a long time to load the screen, but we're just waiting for the task to be canceled. The underlying cancelled method is sendAsync. Why so slow?

Comment: Should this be an adroid service? Also, this problem was happening before I had any cancellation tokens at all, so I'm skeptical that its the problem. I will try your solution though.